# Is there a way to prevent Salesforce from adding a Thread Id to my support emails?

Tags: email, servicecloud

In the email publisher, my subject line looks like this:  `RE: TEST new ticket`

[image]

But when the email is delivered, Salesforce has appended a thread id:  `Re: TEST new ticket   [ ref:_00DA0Be33._500A0QT1h2:ref ]`

[image]

Let's say I know all of the reasons that a thread id is a Good Thing and Very Helpful... but for whatever reason I still don't want to display it on my emails (for example, because product owner doesn't like the aesthetic).  **Is there a way to prevent Salesforce from adding it?**

Comment: It's under case settings and you can choose if it's in the header or footer. I presume you can remove it completely but I'm not in a position to check for you.

Comment: For me it's under cases - email to case. Looks like it would allow me to unchecked both

Comment: Brilliant.  I kept looking under Case Settings, didn't think to look under Email-to-Case.   If you re-post as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 4):

The settings are under case - email to case:

[image: Email to Case menu]

Then in the section there are two checkboxes which define if the thread id is shown in the subject and/or body of the email:
[image: thread id setup]

Just as an aside you can still include the thread id in an email template (auto response for example) as there is a merge field available for it:
[image: thread id merge field]

Comment: As of now, what is the solution to remove the follow up thread